# Pathfinder 2e help with a kobold draconic instinct barbarian build

Tags: character-creation, optimization, pathfinder-2e

Hello all I'm new to Pathfinder 2e and wanted to make a melee kobold barbarian with Dragon Instinct for the Crown of the Kobold King adventure. I'm not sure if its viable? We are using point by in the [Pathbuilder 2e app/website](https://pathbuilder2e.com/) and cannot use 3rd party sources. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to RPG.SE! Would you mind rewriting your question a bit, so it's easier to understand exactly what you need - for instance, which method of point buy and how many points you have available. The language itself may also need some revision, for legibility purposes.

Comment: The [Point Buy](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1301) variant rule which doesn't have different point amounts might be what they're using for this, but I'm not sure Pathbuilder supports that.

Comment: Additionally, it would be nice to know what makes you worried that it isn't viable. Are you specifically concerned about e.g. the lowered Constitution, your Small size, interactions with the adventure, etc.

Answer (score 6):

## It is viable

### Heritage

Dragonscaled (fire) is probably the best. Spellscale is not great, you cannot cast most spells while raging.

### Ancestry feats

**1st level:** [Kobold Breath](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1272) might be tempting, but is not worth the actions without Dragon's Breath, which you won't have. I recommend [Cringe](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1270).
**5th level:** Nothing special.

### Ability Scores

Recently the rules were changed, you can pick any 2 abilities to be increased, I recommend Str and Con.
The previous +2 Dex and Cha are not that useful, and the -2 Con is downright horrible.

For best possible AC you will need +2 Dex, you can select it as one of the 4 you can increase on 1st level.

Starting values: Str 18, Dex 12, Con 16, Wis 12, Int 10, Cha 10. You can switch Cha and Wis, it doesn't matter much either way.

### Background

Anything that gives you Str or Con is great.

- [Martial Disciple](https://2e.aonprd.com/Backgrounds.aspx?ID=24) gives you Athletics (basically any skill) and Quick Jump, while [Farmhand](https://2e.aonprd.com/Backgrounds.aspx?ID=14) gives you Assurance with Athletics
- Mechanic gives you Quick Repair, but you don't really need it before level 3

### Skills

- Medicine can help with healing, especially once you are Expert and have Assurance
- Crafting helps you Repair your shield
- Diplomacy is widely useful

### Skill feats

[Quick Repair](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=827) makes shield repair much faster, but won't really need it before level 3 (Shield Block).

Assurance on Athletics with Quick Jump and Powerful Leap gives you 20 feet Leap on level 4, 25 feet on level 6, which is useful for jumping over things.

Assurance on Medicine gives you reliable healing from level 3. Battle Medicine is not recommended, you will not have enough free hands.

### Class Feats

**1st level:** You need to get to your enemy, so [Sudden Charge](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=134) is very useful.
**2nd level:** Nothing special, a good level to pick up a Dedication. [Sentinel](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=76) or a Champion multiclass gives you heavy armor (+1 AC), very useful for Barbarians.
**4th level:** Nothing special, probably [Swipe](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=142) is best. [Healing Touch](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=689) can be used in combat, while raging if you took Champion Dedication
**6th level:** I guess you want Dragon's Rage Breath.

### General Feats

[Shield Block](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=839), you will need it.

### Equipment

A shield for better AC, from level 3 with Shield Block.
A Battle Axe works well with [Swipe](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=142), and a Trident can be thrown.

For armor you need the heaviest you are proficient with and can afford.

### Magic Items

Crucial
**2nd level:** Potency +1 on your weapon.
**4th level:** Striking on your weapon

Nice to have
**3rd level:** [Crafter's Eyepiece](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=427).
**4th level:** [Sturdy Shield](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=327).

### Tactics

No need to overcomplicate things.

1. Rage
2. Sudden Charge

When you do not need to move, Raise Shield.

### Alternatives

Instead of the weapon + shield you can use a two-handed weapon. Either one with a really big damage die, or one with reach, so you need to move less.

Either way, drop Crafting, Quick Repair and Shield Block. You should pick up the Intimidate skill, the Intimidating Glare skill feat, and pick 12 Cha, or even 14 Cha if you take [Toughness](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=855) on level 3. [Warrior](https://2e.aonprd.com/Backgrounds.aspx?ID=35) is a really good background for this.

Comment: Just for OP to consider, I had a barbarian with that stat spread work quite well using a Greataxe instead of a Shield + Battleaxe. The shield build isn't bad at all (makes the Barb quite tanky), and this is a solid build for OP, but I don't want to give OP the impression that "only shield barbarians are viable".

Comment: @ESCE, what did you do with the 3rd action?

Comment: Often intimidation or moving into flanking position. Lay on Hands once per encounter once that became available. (This char did grab the Champion archetype for Redeemer). Rage also takes an action, so first turn the "third" action would be Rage.

Comment: If you're using a shield, Kobold Weapon Familiarity is a nice alternative to cringe to gain access to the Tricky Pick, an above average 1 handed weapon.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz as he won't crit often, an 1d8 weapon is better than 1d6+Fatal in my opinion. Even with backstabber, especially from level 4 (Striking rune)

Comment: @András I think that's mostly correct, but the difference is close enough, and sufficiently flavorful that I'm comfortable suggesting the option - especially with the modular B/P/S option.